# How to compile program with included header file with C preprocessor macros?

Tags: fortran

I have a header file `types.h` included in my mean program. I would like to know how to compile this program with gfortran.

Here it is the main program:

```
program gauss
implicit none
#include "types.h"

tinteger, parameter :: n=3
treal a(n,n), b(n)

tinteger i, j, k
treal tmp

do i=1,n
   do j=1,n
      A(i,j)=C_PI_R * i+ C_1_5_R * (j-C_1_R) 
   enddo
enddo

do i=1,n
  b(i) = i 
enddo

do j = 1,n-1 
  do i = j+1,n
   a(i,j)     = - a(i,j) / a(j,j)
     do k = j+1,n
       a(i,k) = a(i,k) + a(i,j)*a(j,k)
     enddo
     b(i) = b(i) + a(i,j)*b(j)
   enddo
 enddo

 b(n) = b(n) / a(n,n)  
 do i = n-1,1,-1
   tmp = c_0_r
   do j = i+1,n
     tmp = tmp + a(i,j)*b(j)
   enddo
   b(i) = (b(i)-tmp) / a(i,i)
 enddo

 end program gauss
```

here is the header file "types.h".

```
 #define SIZEOFREAL 8
 #define SIZEOFINT  4
 #define SIZEOFLONGINT  8

 #define TREAL          REAL(SIZEOFREAL)
 #define TINTEGER       INTEGER(SIZEOFINT)
 #define TCOMPLEX       COMPLEX(SIZEOFREAL)
 #define TLONGINTEGER   INTEGER(SIZEOFLONGINT)

 #define M_REAL(x)  FLOAT(x)
 #define C_PI_R     3.14159265358979323846
 #define C_01_R     0.1
 #define C_0125_R   0.125
 #define C_025_R    0.25
 #define C_05_R     0.5
```

Comment: Are you passing this through a preprocessor?

Comment: Yes, I want to declare a source preprocessing variable.

Comment: So, what problem do you get when you try to compile this?  What flags do you use?

Comment: I used the commande gfortran -cpp -E -dM gauss.f90

Comment: "I would like to know how to compile this program with gfortran."  To me, given the command line you give, it looks like you know how to use gfortran.  What is your problem?  I assume that the compiler is complaining about something, but I'm not going to try to guess what the error is.

Comment: It is the first time I use C header that's why I don't know how to compile such a program. When I compile, tinteger and treal that I defined in the type.h header are not identified.

Comment: It is very possible that your problem comes down to the preprocessor being case sensitive.  But, so that we can be sure, please copy the error messages into your question.

Comment: Try gfortran -cpp gauss.f90 (rather than -cpp -E -dM). Otherwise, the preprocessed code will be just printed out... (i.e., no error message!)

Comment: Why do you have `treal` and `tinteger` at the beginning of the program? Is that just a copy/paste error?

Comment: is that the whole header?  besides the CASE issue you have theings like `C_1_5_R` that are not in the header, and also not declared, so will throw errors.

Comment: Thanks for you help, it was just a case sensitive problem, now it works :)

Comment: glad you fixed it, but i would encourage you to use modules instead of monkeying around with cpp.